# Server Error in '/' Application. in c#.net

Tags: c#, mysql

Am passing MYSQL query in C#.Net and am always getting the same error.

**My Query is**

```
    topCustomers.DataSource = GetData("SELECT l.Username , Sum( ad.Amt ) AS Amount ,ad.UserDate FROM adm_advt_answer ad" +
                              "JOIN adm_advt_question adq ON ad.Q_ID = adq.nID" +
                              " INNERJOIN login l ON adq.Buserid = l.Buserid WHERE adq.Buserid = '" + username + "' AND adq.Active='Y' AND date( ad.UserDate ) = '2014-02-20'" +
                              " GROUP BY UserId");
    topCustomers.DataBind();
```

Please correct my syntax.

**My Error is**

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'adm_advt_question adq ON ad.Q_ID = adq.nID INNERJOIN login l ON adq.Buserid = l.' at line 1

Comment: Please format your question...

Comment: INNERJOIN should be INNER JOIN

Comment: You also need a space at the start of this string: "JOIN adm_advt_question adq ON ad.Q_ID = adq.nID" +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `INNER JOIN` instead of `INNERJOIN`.

```
topCustomers.DataSource = GetData("SELECT l.Username , Sum( ad.Amt ) AS Amount
,ad.UserDate FROM adm_advt_answer ad " +//Notice the space at ending
"JOIN adm_advt_question adq ON ad.Q_ID = adq.nID" +
" INNER JOIN login l ON adq.Buserid = l.Buserid WHERE adq.Buserid = '" + username + "' AND   
adq.Active='Y' AND date( ad.UserDate ) = '2014-02-20'" +
" GROUP BY UserId");
```

You should consider using `PreparedStatements` to avoid `sql injection`.(for the parameter `username`)